# Mysql crashed and Stopped unexpectly

Tags: mysql

I work on localhost and today Mysql stopped unexpectedly here is log :

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-12-28 10:01:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-12-28 10:01:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-12-28 10:01:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-12-28 10:01:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-12-28 10:01:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-12-28 10:01:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-12-28 10:01:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-12-28 10:01:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2319556
2019-12-28 10:01:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-12-28 10:01:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-12-28 10:01:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-12-28 10:01:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp2\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-12-28 10:01:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp2\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-12-28 10:01:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-12-28 10:01:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 2319565; transaction id 821
2019-12-28 10:01:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp2\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-12-28 10:01:41 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-12-28 10:01:41 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the log for the restart. It does not tell us/you anything about why the previous execution crashed, just that the restart/recovery seems to have worked. To investigate the crash, if at all possible, you need to check the mysql log and/or your system logs prior to the restart.

Comment: And ask the question at the dba sister site of SO, since SO deals with programming questions only and this is an admin question.